# system disk almost full after using rclone

Tags: disk-space, macos-mojave

Today I tried out rclone to backup files to a webdav server. I used the crypt option to encrypt the files before uploading. rclone copied about 8GB to the server, and I checked if it really uploaded that much. It generated lots of notices and errors in the terminal because of filenames that were too long.

I had about 12GB free at the start, now only 3GB left. `~/Library/Logs` size is 155MB. `~/Library/Caches` size is 3GB.

I'm not sure if it's rclone's crypt function that used up 8GB of disk space, or if it's the terminal, or some other log file.

How can I free up those 8GB?

Answer (score 0):

I purged the remote content, and that freed up my local disk. I suppose the crypt option keeps a local copy and takes up all disk space.